# Finding income ratio by student status

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I'm new to R and for an exam he is asking way over our heads on a question for a newbie. ***Any point in right direction would be greatly appreciated.***

Using the **Default** dataset, we are supposed to create a **95% confidence interva**l using the *difference* in **median balance to income ratio by student status**.

Not sure **how to find the income ratio by student status.** Assuming I am supposed to be doing something with bootstrapping by the end of the question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read and edit your question according to: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that we could help you. Without input data and wanted output it's impossible to answer (and understand) your question.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing... the exact question given is "Using the Default dataset, create a 95% confidence interval for the difference in median balance to income ratio by student status."

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to ask for external help on an **exam** question?

Comment: I don't want the actual answer, we are allowed to google and look for external help. I just want a point in the right direction to what I should be looking at to help me begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base off nothing here is how I interperet this question:

The ratio will be between the columns 'balance' and 'income'. Here is how to obtain that value:

```
 dds$ratio <- dds$balance/dds$income #where dds is your default data set and you may need to replace 'balance and 'income' with whatever is in your dataset
```

Now you will need to group by the status. One way to do this is to use `dplyr` like this:

```
 dds %>%
   group_by(status) %>%    # replace status with whatever your column is named
   summarise(Median=median(ratio))
```

Now you will need to use whichever statistical test you feel appropriate and calculate the associated 95% confidence interval.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I greatly appreciate it. I was going insane trying to figure out how to start this lol

Comment: No worries :) hope the rest of your exam goes well!